# How can i browse a website locally with IIS manager?

Tags: domain-name-system, iis, windows-server-2016, iis-10

I have a website, hosted on server named "A". (production, the nameservers point at this server)

I just purchased a VPS server, named "B". (test, no nameservers pointing anything)

On the second server I have setup within IIS, the same website as in server "A"

Upon selecting the option within `IIS manager`

```
Browse example.com on xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:80 (http)
```

the internet explorer browser, opens the website hosted on server "A" and not the one locally at server "B".

How can I browse the website hosted locally on server "B"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can edit your "hosts" file so that the web site name points to server B's IP address; that will bypass DNS.

Comment: That is great. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can also use 127.0.0.1 in the browser on the local machine, either http or https or both, however you have it setup. That should pull up the local web server. Also on the right side of the IIS Manager, when you highlight the website on the left you should have the option Browse this website. On either 80 or 443